# Error With Installing Virtualenv With Pip and Homebrew

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, osx-mavericks

I am trying to get a nice clean Python environment setup on OSX 10.9.  I've installed Python with Homebrew and set my PATH variables so...

```
> which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

and

```
> which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

so when I look at my /usr/local/bin :

```
pip -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pip
python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python
```

then when I run:

```
> pip install virtualenv
```

I get permission errors on /usr/local/bin/virtualenv:

```
...
running install_scripts

Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/bin

error: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: Permission denied
```

I thought that by using Homebrew I could use pip and avoid using sudo to install virtualenv. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't know what homebrew is all about but I always `sudo pip install` outside the virtualenv and just `pip install` inside a virtualenv

Comment: do you have virtualenv already installed? do `which virtualenv`.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix It looks like I do. `which virtualenv` returned `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` I tried to do `pip uninstall virtualenv` but it's still there. How can I get rid of this and start fresh?

Comment: @DorkRawk why would you get rid of virtualenv? now just create virtualenv with it since its there.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix It looks like I had try to install it with sudo before and that's why I was getting a Permissions error. See my answer below.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DorkRawk Yes, you couldn't install over it because it was already present. The thing is that if I'm not mistaken, you might have just deleted the virtualenv of OSx...  because mine is installed under root too and I don't remember installing it. Having virtualenv installed as root doesn't prevent you from using it btw.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I just went back and checked in /usr/local/bin after doing the reinstall with pip (as in my answer) and I now have a `virutalenv` and `virtualenv-2.7` in my /usr/local/bin but my user is the owner, rather than root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok! I managed to fix this myself.

I deleted all the virtualenv related things from `/usr/local/bin` (they had been installed under root for some reason and this was causing my permission issues.).

Then I did a `pip uninstall virtualenv` to get rid of other instances of virtualenv, as there was still one in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Then a simple `pip install virtualenv` and things work fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely HomeBrew does some magic so that running `brew install` allows writing to `/usr/local/bin`, but this privilege is not available to normal commands. This is a guess, I didn't investigate this further.

Install `virtualenv` with `brew`:

```
 brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

This command:

> pip install virtualenv

runs pip from your first directory from $PATH environment variable, which is usually system wide, thus when you run in this way - you are trying to install it globall.

You should install you your environment in your $HOME directory:

```
virtualenv $HOME/myvirpython
```

and later:

```
$HOME/myvirpython/bin pip install something
```

Additionally you should read this:

https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python